# Editor permission for pieces

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm trying to grant **editor** permissions on specific pieces for any editor. Try applying as described in [apostrophe-permissions](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/permissions.html) and [permissionsFields](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/reusable-content-with-pieces.html#fine-grained-permissions-for-pieces). However, I still can't get my editors to be able to edit any piece they want, even if they haven't created it.

This is what I have in my `app.js`:

```
'apostrophe-users': {
      groups: [
        {
          title: 'editor',
          permissions: [ 'edit-placementGuide', 'edit-market','edit-email-template' ]
        },
        {
          title: 'admin',
          permissions: [ 'admin' ]
        }
      ]
    },
```

Pieces appeared on the **AdminBar**, **Manage modals** can be opened, but none of the pieces are listed on the modals, or can be edited.

What am I missing? Does something need to be set up at the `lib\modules\piece-name\index.js`?

Thanks,

D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

admin-placementGuide is the right choice to have total control of one type. edit- is the right to make one and, if enabled, to be assigned rights to others.