# Having issues with permissions on Apostrophe production

Tags: apostrophe-cms

In my current Apostrophe installation I have set some permissions for editors and admin as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767506/editor-permission-for-pieces).
However, permissions are working as expected on my local copy but not in production. Meaning my editors can't edit the widgets on the piece, even though they have access to edit fields on the edit-modal.

Also, I'd like them to be able to edit tags and images but settings as below don't work.

```
{
          title: 'editor',
          permissions: [ 'admin-placementGuide', 'admin-market', 'edit-images', 'edit-tags' ]
        },
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Thanks,
D

Comment: Are these users actually in the `editor` group? Check their settings. I'm not sure if this production database is a recent copy of your dev database or a separately built-out set of content.

Comment: They are set as editors, they have access to the editor-modal. On my local, I'm actually using exact same code and database.

Comment: They can create pieces but not edit them. Also, I check both Apostrophe versions just in case and they are both using same version 2.0. Having said that, the admin bar menu is different. `Global` option on production, but `Pages` option instead in my local.

Comment: What exact version? They are both using that exact version? (node_modules/apostrophe/package.json will tell you)

Comment: Local 2.52.0 and production 2.26.1

Comment: Apparently there is a conflict with permissions on 2.26.1. Updated version to `2.56.0` and it's working now. One more thing from the questions above ^^, how to give them edit permissions on tags and images? `edit-apostrophe-images` and `edit-apostrophe-tags` are not working

Comment: If you have resolved the problem by upgrading I would recommend that you answer your own question for posterity.

"edit" means "can make one, or edit one I've been specifically granted control of." You probably wanted "admin" of those types. "apostrophe-tags" is an adminOnly type, meaning only global sitewide admins can edit them, because they have "ripple effects" on all pieces in the system. Much like editing users or groups it doesn't make sense to let anyone but admins globally edit tags.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved by upgrading to the latest version of 2.x to obtain bug fixes released some time ago.